# Como imprimir na tela ou console , um array de strings em php

Tags: php, array, foreach, for

Estive vendo a documentação mas não está claro como eu faço isso.
Eu tenho um array de strings:

```
$remetente = $con->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['rem']);
$arrai= array();
$remetenteArray[] = str_split($remetente, 1);
```

Como podem ver, o `$remetenteArray[]` é um array de strings, sendo que estas strings tem apenas um caractere cada. O que eu preciso é iterar sobre esse esse array e **imprimir na tela somente os números** que houverem nele, e salvar eles em uma string.

Vou criar uma expressão regular pra pegar os números, mas o problema nesse momento é como imprimir essas strings que formam o array...

Comment: `str_split` torna uma string num array de letras, para iterar em cada letra. Qual o conteudo de `$remetente` ? Ou você quer imprimir só as letras que sejam números ?

Comment: Eu quero salvar em um array somente as strings que sejam números.

Comment: Mas o que tem `$remetente` ? E o que você gostava que `$remetenteArray[]` tivesse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você deseja é verificar individualmente cada elemento do *array*. Ou seja, seria algo assim:

```
for ($i=(int)0; $i<count($remetenteArray); $i++){
    print ">".$remetenteArray[$i]."< ";
}
```

Creio que você deva ter tentado algo parecido e aí recebeu algo como:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in ..
```

Acontece que você cometeu um erro ao definir o *array*:

```
$remetenteArray[] = str_split($remetente, 1);
```

Ao colocar o abre e fecha colchetes você criou um *array* dentro do outro, ou seja, o primeiro item dele contém o *array* resultante da função `str_split()` daí basta removê-los que o laço funcionará corretamente.

Mas como o que você quer é retornar só os números da *string* dentro do *array*, não há nem a necessidade de fazer este malabarismo todo, crie uma função que recebe a *string* e cuspa logo o *array* desejado.

```
function onlyNumbers($str){
        $result=[];
        for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
                $j = substr($str, $i,1);
                if ($j>="0" and $j<="9") $result[]=$j;
        }
        return $result;
}
```

Assim:

```
$remetente = "0 A 1 B 2 C 3 D 4";
print_r(onlyNumber($remetente));
```

Resultará em:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

Aliás, foi graças ao `print_r()` que descobri seu erro. :-)

Comment: Show! Mas esses números que eu extraí do array de string, eu gostaria que eles formassem uma única  String, e não um array.

Comment: Eu vou usar esse conjunto de números $remetente numa consulta mysqli:  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO forum (codUsuario,titulo,mensagem) VALUES('$result','$titulo','$mensagem');");

Comment: Tentei usar a função implode() pra converter o array de n[umeros em uma única String, mas o php fica acusando "array to string conversion" na linha da query...

Comment: Se é pra ser uma coisa só, troque o `$result=[]` por `$result=""` no começo da função e o `$result[]=$j` por `$result=.$j;` e o resultado será uma única string.